# Como mando esta información de hijo a padre en REACT / NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, state

Tengo una clase padre que es una page de NextJS el cual renderiza un listado de vídeos, para el cual cada listado es un componente hijo "VideoList". Lo que quiero hacer es que desde VideoList, cuando se eliga un video, se actualize el estado de la page selectedVideo de forma que pueda renderizar otro componente dependiendo de este estado.

Clase padre (Masterclass)

```
const getSections = (masterclasses: IMasterclass[]) => {
  let sections: ISection[] = [];

  masterclasses.forEach((mc) => {
    let found = false;
    let i = 0;
    while (sections[i] && !found) {
      if (sections[i].name === mc.section.name) {
        found = true;
        sections[i].videos?.push(mc);
      }
      i++;
    }
    if (!found) {
      sections.push({
        name: mc.section.name,
        image: mc.section.image,
        videos: [mc],
      });
    }
  });

  return sections;
};

const Masterclass = () => {
  const [sections, setSections] = useState<ISection[]>();
  const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState<IMasterclass>();
  let { t } = useTranslation();

  const handleVideoClick = (video:any) => {
    console.log(video.target)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialMasterclasses().then((res) => {
      const sectionsList = getSections(res);
      setSections(sectionsList);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Head />
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1>{t("masterclass:title")}</h1>
        {sections !== undefined ? (
          sections.map((section) => {
            return (
              <div key={section.name}>
                <VideoList 
                  key={section.name}
                  title={capitalizeFirstLetter(section.name)}
                  // HAY QUE CAMBIAR LOS VIDEOS -> MOCKS DE PRUEBA PARA ORDENACIÓN
                  videos={section.videos ?? []} //{videos} // section.videos ? section.videos : []
                  handleVideoClick={setSelectedVideo}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <h1>No hay secciones</h1>
        )}
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Masterclass;
```

Clase hijo (VideoList)

```
interface VideoListProps {
  title: string;
  videos: IMasterclass[];
  handleVideoClick: any;
}

const VideoList = ({ title, videos, handleVideoClick }: VideoListProps) => {
  const [filterSelected, setFilterSelected] = useState<string>("");
  const [sortedVideos, setSortedVideos] = useState<IMasterclass[]>(videos);

  let { t } = useTranslation();

  const options = [
    t("masterclass:filter_option1"),
    t("masterclass:filter_option2"),
    t("masterclass:filter_option3"),
    t("masterclass:filter_option4"),
  ];

  const sortByFilter = (filter: string): void => {
    switch (filter) {
      case options[0]:
        setSortedVideos([
          ...sortedVideos.sort((a, b) => {
            const a_date = new Date(a.createdAt);
            const b_date = new Date(b.createdAt);
            return a_date.getUTCDate() - b_date.getUTCDate();
          }),
        ]);
        break;
      case options[1]:
        setSortedVideos([
          ...sortedVideos.sort((a, b) => {
            const a_date = new Date(a.createdAt);
            const b_date = new Date(b.createdAt);
            return b_date.getUTCDate() - a_date.getUTCDate();
          }),
        ]);
        break;
      default:
        setSortedVideos([...sortedVideos]);
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (e: any) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setFilterSelected(value);
  };

  const handleClick = (e:any) => {
    console.log(e)
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    sortByFilter(filterSelected);
  }, [filterSelected]);

  return (
    <>
      <section className={styles.videolist_section}>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <InputSelect
          name={"filter"}
          label={t("masterclass:filter_selection_title")}
          title={"Ordenar por"} // Coger de local/es
          options={options}
          width={30}
          onChange={handleFilterChange}
          disabled={false}
          optional={true}
        />
        <div>
          <HorizontalScrollSelector>
            {sortedVideos.map((video) => {
              return (
                <div key={video.id} className={styles.video}>
                  <StandardThumbnail
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    locked={false}
                    selected={false}
                    image={"/assets/images/lol-logo.png"} /* TODO - Cambiar rutas de imagenes */
                  />
                  <h1>{video.createdAt}</h1>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </HorizontalScrollSelector>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoList;
```

Como se ve en el código del hijo, se renderizan un listado de vídeos mediante un map. Pues bien, lo que quiero hacer es que ese video que se está usando en el map sea el que se pase al padre como un objeto y modificar el estado del padre.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es pasar un método como prop a `VideoList`. Sin embargo, lo estás haciendo de forma incorrecta.
En `MasterClass` declaras el método `handleVideoClick`, sin embargo, cuando lo pasas a `VideoList` lo haces de la siguiente manera `handleVideoClick={setSelectedVideo}`. Lo anterior es incorrecto ya que `setSelectedVideo` no existe en `Masterclass`. Por lo tanto la clase `Masterclass debe quedar de la siguiente forma.`

```
const Masterclass = () => {
    ...

    const handleVideoClick = (video:any) => {
        console.log(video.target)
    }

    // Posteriormente en tu render realizas un 
    <VideoList 
        key={section.name}
        title={capitalizeFirstLetter(section.name)}
        // HAY QUE CAMBIAR LOS VIDEOS -> MOCKS DE PRUEBA PARA ORDENACIÓN
        videos={section.videos ?? []} //{videos} // section.videos ? section.videos : []
        handleVideoClick={handleVideoClick}
    />
}
```

Posteriormente en `VideoList` tienes dos errores. El primero es que no estás llamando al método `handleClick` correctamente para poder pasarle un parámetro desde el `render`.
Por lo tanto, la forma correcta de llamarlo desde el render es:

```
<HorizontalScrollSelector>
  {sortedVideos.map((video) => {
    return (
      <div key={video.id} className={styles.video}>
        <StandardThumbnail
          onClick={() => { handleClick(video) }}
          locked={false}
          selected={false}
          image={"/assets/images/lol-logo.png"} /* TODO - Cambiar rutas de imagenes */
        />
        <h1>{video.createdAt}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</HorizontalScrollSelector>
```

Finalmente, desde el método `handleClick` de `VideoList` deberías poder comunicarte con el padre de la siguiente forma:

```
const handleClick = (e:any) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.props.handleVideoClick(e);
}
```